# How do I terminate a while loop in a function, using another function. (Tic Tac Toe game)

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe program in Python. I have made the functions to print the board, take user input and actually play the game (the board changes with every input). However, I can't seem to run my `output(gboard)` function in my main `exec()` function to terminate the `while True:` loop. Here's the code:

```
def board(gboard):
    print("\n"*10)
    print(gboard[7]+'|'+gboard[8]+'|'+gboard[9])
    print(gboard[4]+'|'+gboard[5]+'|'+gboard[6])
    print(gboard[1]+'|'+gboard[2]+'|'+gboard[3])


def outcome(gboard):
    global ini
    if(gboard[1] == 'X') and (gboard[2] == 'X') and gboard[3] == 'X':
        print('Winner is X!')
        ini = 0
        return ini



def exec():
    move_counter = 0
    ini = 1
    winner = 'X'
    outcomes = ['X','O']

    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!")
    print("Here's how the game works:\nEach number on the keypad represents a place on the table.")
    print("For example the number 1 stands for the box in column 1 row 3, while number 6 stands for column 3 row 2.")
    print("You will tell the computer where you wish to play using this system!")
    print("\n"*2+"Here is a visual representation of the board and the key numbers: ")
    print('7|8|9')
    print('4|5|6')
    print('1|2|3')
    print('If you wish to play X in the middle, you tell the computer to place X in position 5. Here is how a blank board will evolve:')
    print(' | | ')
    print(' |X| ')
    print(' | | ')
    print("So. Let's play!")

    player2 = None
    player1 = input('Player 1, would you like to be X or O(represents the letter)?: ')
    player1 = player1.upper()
    if(player1 == 'X'):
        player2 = 'O'
    else:
        player2 = 'X'
    print(f"Ok. Player 1 is {player1} and so that means that Player 2 is {player2}")


    gboard = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
    while True:
        move = int(input('Player 1, where would you like to play?: '))
        gboard[move] = player1
        move_counter += 1
        board(gboard)
        outcome(gboard)
        if(ini == 0) or move_counter == 9:
            break

        move2 = int(input('Player 2, where would you like to play?: '))
        gboard[move2] = player2
        move_counter += 1
        board(gboard)
        outcome(gboard)

        if(ini == 0) or move_counter == 9:
            break





    print('DONE!')
exec()
```

In that code, I have only entered one win condition, if the bottom row is all X - that's what I use to test the program. When I run the program, and enter the bottom row with X, it prints 'Winner is X!' but doesn't break the while loop. However, when the move_counter reaches 9, it breaks the while loop. Here is the execution:

```
  Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
Here's how the game works:
Each number on the keypad represents a place on the table.
For example the number 1 stands for the box in column 1 row 3, while number 6 stands for column 3 row 2.
You will tell the computer where you wish to play using this system!


Here is a visual representation of the board and the key numbers:
7|8|9
4|5|6
1|2|3
If you wish to play X in the middle, you tell the computer to place X in position 5. Here is how a blank board will evolve:
 | |
 |X|
 | |
So. Let's play!
Player 1, would you like to be X or O(represents the letter)?: X
Ok. Player 1 is X and so that means that Player 2 is O
Player 1, where would you like to play?: 1
 | |
 | |
X| |
Player 2, where would you like to play?: 4
 | |
O| |
X| |
Player 1, where would you like to play?: 2
 | |
O| |
X|X|
Player 2, where would you like to play?: 5
 | |
O|O|
X|X|
Player 1, where would you like to play?: 3
 | |
O|O|
X|X|X
Winner is X!
Player 2, where would you like to play?:
```

I don't expect the program to ask Player 2, where they would like to play after the winner is decided. Why isn't my outcome function breaking out of the while loop?

Comment: Once the winner of the round is announced, is it your goal to close the program immediately?

Comment: The "ini" in "exec" is local to this function. By the way: "exec" is a function in standard library. You should use another name.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `ini` variable in your `exec` function is different from the `ini` variable from the `outcome` function (one is local and one is global variable). You can fix this simply by declaring `ini` in `exec` function as a global variable like this:

```
def exec():
    move_counter = 0
    global ini <------- here
    ini = 1
    winner = 'X'
    outcomes = ['X','O']
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You set in your exec() ini=1 so even if its set to 0 by winning, it will be set to 1 again.
You can remove the ini=1 from your exec and declare it above all methods, so that it will have the value 1 when the game begins and will just be set to 0 when it ends.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't my outcome function breaking out of the while loop?

Because `ini` is still equal to 1. Your main function has a local variable named `ini`, so even if you set the global `ini` from `outcome`, it will be ignored.

You should not use a global variable for this. You have the right idea with `return ini`. However, the calling code does not care about this *name* - it only cares about the *value*. When you call `outcome` and X has won, it will `return` the value of `0`. You should assign this:

```
ini = outcome(gboard)
```

The next step is that `outcome` needs to return a value even if X did *not* win. (And, of course, you should test for the other ways that X can win, and that O can win.) You can use multiple different values to indicate who won, or if the game should continue.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your `ini` var as a **global variable**.

Try putting it at the beginning, outside of the method' scopes and import the `global ini` inside of them.

---

```
ini = None # <--- declare ini as global without value  

def board(gboard):
    print("\n"*10)
    print(gboard[7]+'|'+gboard[8]+'|'+gboard[9])
    print(gboard[4]+'|'+gboard[5]+'|'+gboard[6])
    print(gboard[1]+'|'+gboard[2]+'|'+gboard[3])


def outcome(gboard):
    global ini
    if(gboard[1] == 'X') and (gboard[2] == 'X') and gboard[3] == 'X':
        print('Winner is X!')
        ini = 0
        return ini



def exec():
    global ini # <--- import ini global in this scope
    move_counter = 0
    ini = 1
    winner = 'X'
    outcomes = ['X','O']

    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!")
    print("Here's how the game works:\nEach number on the keypad represents a place on the table.")
    print("For example the number 1 stands for the box in column 1 row 3, while number 6 stands for column 3 row 2.")
    print("You will tell the computer where you wish to play using this system!")
    print("\n"*2+"Here is a visual representation of the board and the key numbers: ")
    print('7|8|9')
    print('4|5|6')
    print('1|2|3')
    print('If you wish to play X in the middle, you tell the computer to place X in position 5. Here is how a blank board will evolve:')
    print(' | | ')
    print(' |X| ')
    print(' | | ')
    print("So. Let's play!")

    player2 = None
    player1 = input('Player 1, would you like to be X or O(represents the letter)?: ')
    player1 = player1.upper()
    if(player1 == 'X'):
        player2 = 'O'
    else:
        player2 = 'X'
    print(f"Ok. Player 1 is {player1} and so that means that Player 2 is {player2}")


    gboard = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
    while True:
        move = int(input('Player 1, where would you like to play?: '))
        gboard[move] = player1
        move_counter += 1
        board(gboard)
        outcome(gboard)
        if(ini == 0) or move_counter == 9:
            break

        move2 = int(input('Player 2, where would you like to play?: '))
        gboard[move2] = player2
        move_counter += 1
        board(gboard)
        outcome(gboard)

        if(ini == 0) or move_counter == 9:
            break





    print('DONE!`enter code here`')
exec()
```